# Dependable textbox autocomplete method

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

[page image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUVHL.jpg)This Images shows my page where i am facing a problem, i want my 'company' textbox get autocomplete by value fetched from database when i input a value in 'code'.

in a seperate page mysql queries will run to get company where code='*'

Both 'code' and 'company' are present in my database[database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wbswe.jpg)

Tried lots of techniques but failed to achieve anything. 
Please help!!

Comment: Could you provide some code that you have already written? You need to edit your question to make it more readable too. As to your `input` tags, you can add backticks ( ` ) to format them correctly. For your pieces of code, you can also use the code editor to insert a snippet.

Comment: Also, did you try [jQueryUI's autocomplete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)? It's quite good.

Answer (score 0):

Give us some code please.

You want to submit form and then, on new page - enter a value to new form with second textbox?

As you probably know - if you want to get data from database you must use classic SQL query in PHP file.

But - if you want do dynamicaly autocomplete second textbox without submit - you can use jQuery:

```
$('#your_textbox').on('input', function() {
    /* This will be fired every time, when textbox's value changes. */
    $('#your_second_textbox').val($('#yout_textbox').val(''));
} );
```